# How can i direct in ActionFilterAttribute on .NET 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-7.0

After I should change request path param for case insensitive, I need redirect same endpoint but with new request path. Endpoint worked with old request path after from I tried like this way

```
context.HttpContext.Request.Path = foodPath;
await next();
```

Finally, I took request path and changed it for case insensitive but I can't redirect and I have not any idea.

NOTE: I use .NET 7

Thanks for your help.

```
    public sealed class FoodVerificationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public FoodVerificationAttribute() { }

        public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
            ActionExecutingContext context,
            ActionExecutionDelegate next
        )
        {
            // get request path value
            var foodPath = await GetRequestValueByHttpMethod(context.HttpContext.Request);

            if (foodPath.Contains('/'))
            {
                foodPath = CheckPathValueForToUpper(foodPath, foods);
                context.HttpContext.Request.Path = foodPath;
                // to-do: redirect

            }

            if (foods.Any(x => foodPath.Contains(x)))
            {
                ...
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    ...
                );
            }
        }
```

I took request path and change but I can't redirect it with new request path.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a "redirect" within the action filter? If so, could you pls try this code?   `public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context){var url = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;if (url == "/home/privacy"){context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Error" }));context.Result.ExecuteResultAsync(context); }}`

Comment: I don't mean this like. I want change `context.HttpContext.Request.Path` and than redirect with new path in endpoint.

Comment: You might put your mouse to `context.HttpContext.Request.Path` in VS and see if the pop up shows it contains a set method. Or you could check if there's a change path method in `context.HttpContext.Request`, if not then I'm afraid we don't have that feature.